# Transformations with Qt and C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing a program to draw an arc and move/rotate it according to the position of the mouse cursor :

[image: initial position]

This image illustrates the scene when the program is first run.
The following images illustrates what is displayed after a mouse click. The mouse click happened at the top right point of the line.

[image: position after mouse click]

After getting the coordinates of the intersection point (between the line and the circle), I want to set the position of the center of the arc to the intersection point.
But, as you can see, the arc is not where I wish it was. Strangely, when I draw a rectangle whose topLeft point is at the intersection point, it works :

[image]

I guess the problem has to be with scene/parent/item coordinates... But I can't find where :/

Here is a sample of the code : (DrawingScene inherits QGraphicsScene)

```
void DrawingScene::drawStates(){
    m_ellipse = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(80.0, 80.0,120.0,120.0);
    addItem(m_ellipse);
    m_arc = new GraphicArcItem(62.0, 62.0,50.0,50.0);
    m_arc->setParentItem(m_ellipse);
    m_arc->setStartAngle(0);
    m_arc->setSpanAngle(270 * 16);
    QLineF line_vertical(140.0,80.0,140.0,200.0);
    addLine(line_vertical);
    QLineF line_horizontal(80.0,140.0,200.0,140.0);
    addLine(line_horizontal);
    QLineF line(QPointF(62.0,62.0), QPointF(140.0,140.0));
    m_lineToCenter = new QGraphicsLineItem(line);
    addItem(m_lineToCenter);
}

void DrawingScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    p1 = event->scenePos();
    QLineF lineToCenter(QPointF(140.0,140.0), p1);
    m_lineToCenter->setLine(lineToCenter);
    QLineF horizontalLine(QPointF(140.0,140.0),QPointF(200.0,140.0));
    double angleBetweenLines = horizontalLine.angleTo(lineToCenter);
    double x = 60.0 * cos(angleBetweenLines * 3.14 / 180.0);
    double y = -60.0 * sin(angleBetweenLines * 3.14 / 180.0);
    QPointF intersectionPoint(x,y);
    QPointF topLeft = intersectionPoint + QPointF(140.0,140.0);
    addRect(QRectF(topLeft, QSizeF(60.0,60.0)));
    m_arc->setPos(topLeft);
}
```

Any help would be more than welcome :)

edit :
Working code for moving the arc :

```
p1 = event->scenePos();
QLineF lineToCenter(QPointF(140.0,140.0), p1);//center of circle to mouse position
double angleBetweenPositions = lineToCenter.angleTo(m_lineToCenter->line()); 
m_lineToCenter->setLine(lineToCenter);
QLineF horizontalLine(QPointF(140.0,140.0),QPointF(200.0,140.0));
double angleBetweenLines = horizontalLine.angleTo(lineToCenter);

double x = 60.0 * cos(angleBetweenLines * 3.14 / 180.0);
double y = -60.0 * sin(angleBetweenLines * 3.14 / 180.0);
QPointF newPoint(x,y);
QPointF ellipse_center = m_ellipse->rect().center();
QPointF intersection_point = intersection_point + ellipse_center;
GraphicArcItem *arc2 = new GraphicArcItem(intersection_point.rx()- 25.0,
                                          intersection_point.ry() - 25.0,50.0,50.0);
addItem(arc2);
m_arc->setPos(intersection_point.rx()-85.0, intersection_point.ry() - 85.0);//why 85 ??
```

Code for the rotation :

```
m_arc->setCurrentRotation(m_arc->getCurrentRotation() + angleBetweenPositions);
m_arc->setTransformOriginPoint(m_arc->getCenter());
m_arc->setRotation(m_arc->getCurrentRotation());
```

Edit : Here are the key parts of the code solving the problem :

```
/*Return the center point of the arc in the parent coordinates*/
QPointF GraphicArcItem::getCenter(){
int xCenter = rect().x() + rect().width()/2;
int yCenter = rect().y() + rect().height()/2;
QPointF center = /*mapToParent(*/QPointF(xCenter,yCenter)/*)*/;
return center;
}

p1 = event->scenePos();
QPointF ellipse_center = m_ellipse->rect().center();
QLineF lineToCenter(ellipse_center, p1);//center of circle to mouse position
double angleBetweenPositions = lineToCenter.angleTo(m_lineToCenter->line());
QLineF horizontalLine(ellipse_center,QPointF(200.0,140.0));
double angleBetweenLines = horizontalLine.angleTo(lineToCenter);
double x = 60.0 * cos(angleBetweenLines * 3.14 / 180.0);
double y = -60.0 * sin(angleBetweenLines * 3.14 / 180.0);
QPointF newPoint(x,y);
QPointF intersection_point = newPoint + ellipse_center;
m_arc->setPos(intersection_point.rx() - 85.0, intersection_point.ry() - 85.0);
m_arc->setCurrentRotation(angleBetweenPositions);
QPointF rotation_center = m_arc->mapFromItem(m_arc, m_arc->getCenter());
m_arc->setTransformOriginPoint(rotation_center);
m_arc->setRotation(m_arc->getCurrentRotation());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectangle and the arc have different parents (the scene is the parent of the rectangle and `m_ellipse` of the arc, hence the references of their coordinates are different. To test it just add a new arc/circle (different from `m_arc` and without using `setParentItem(m_ellipse);`) to the scene - it should have the correct screen position. To achieve the desired result I would suggest you to play with `mapTo<something>`/`mapFrom<something>` methods. I presume that [mapToParent](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mapToParent) will do the trick, but you should check it anyway.

Comment: If I remove the line `m_arc->setParentItem(m_ellipse);`, then the parent of the `m_arc` would be the scene right ?

Comment: Correct. This alone should do the trick, but I presume it would affect the rest of the program's logic. That's why in such cases a mapping is used.

Comment: It doesn't change the program logic, I had put this line in an attempt to solve my problem... but removing it doesn't solve the problem... :/

Comment: My bad, there is an improvment... Now, it draws on the opposite point of the circle... Let me think about it
I'll let you know :)

Comment: For example, if I click on the right side of the circle, the arc appears on the left side. It seems like there is a symetry to the point or central symetry (not sure of the english expression ahahah)

Comment: @JulietteMarquis, could you please check the coordinates as values

Comment: @JulietteMarquis, also have in mind that the math equations (e.g. `double x = 60.0 * cos(angleBetweenLines * 3.14 / 180.0);`) consider the y-axis from bottom to top (0,0 is at the bottom-left corner), however in Qt it is top to bottom (0,0 is at the top-left corner)

Comment: Is it the same with QtMath : qCos ?

Comment: So, the solution is working with the code I edited in my post :)
the problem was that I was doing a rotation at the same time (which I had not mentioned, sorry) 
Now, my problem is to merge the two features. Both works on their own, but when I tried to merge them, the behaviour is rather random :/

Comment: @JulietteMarquis, which are the two features and what is this random behaviour?

Comment: One feature is to move the arc to the intersection point. The other feature is to rotate the arc by an angle corresponding to the angle betwen the initial line (from the center of the arc to the center of the circle) and the new line (from the intersection point to the center of the circle) so that the open part of the arc is always towards the center of the circle :)

The random behaviour is that the arc is drawn in random places in the scene (I could'nt say if there is a logic behind...)

Comment: @JulietteMarquis, when you rotate a shape, you don't only rotate the shape within its coordinate system, you rotate the whole coordinate system. So, the next coordinates will be taken with regard to the rotated axes, hence the "randomness" of the places it appears on the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your time ! :)
I had other things to do but I finally got time to work on this topic and I succeeded !

Comment: @JulietteMarquis, I am glad to hear that!